# How to stratch ListView to the bottom of the screen when virtual keyboard is displayed?

Tags: android, listview, xamarin.forms

I have `ContentPage` with this:

```
this.Content = new StackLayout { Children = {
        new Label { Text = "Block 1:", FontSize = 18 },
        Entry1,
        myListView,
        new Label { Text = "Block 2:", FontSize = 18 },
        Entry2,
        Entry3
    }
};
```

The problem is - when I select `Entry` control I want to see as much of `myListView` as possible but controls from below moves above keyboard and block most part of `myListView`.

How to solve such problem?

[image]

Comment: Which version is your android project targeting? Mine is like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4NFi.png) and I'm using Emulator with Android 6.0, by default it behaviors like what you need: [JIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQPgI.gif).

Answer (score 0):

On your `MainActivity.cs` set `WindowSoftInputMode = SoftInput.AdjustNothing` to disable UI resizing when showing the virtual keyboard.
Example:

```
[Activity(ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait, WindowSoftInputMode = SoftInput.AdjustNothing...)]
```